# How to specify a directory without an absolute path in Sikuli

Tags: jython, sikuli

I'm attempting to use the current directory in which the script is currently located in Sikuli to create a .txt document to output results to. So far the only way I've got this to work so far is by using an absolute path with the file already created, but this script will be exported and used on multiple machines.

I've currently tried using the import os and using os.path.basename as suggested by the manual, but this does not appear to be working for me. So far the only functionality I have is by having the file already created and using an absolute reference to it

This is what the manual is suggesting:

```
file = open(os.path.basename('/NewSikulix/Keyboard_Shortcuts.sikuli/Results.txt'), 'w')
```

This is what I currently have that works:

```
file = open("D:\NewSikulix\Keyboard_Shortcuts.sikuli\Results.txt" ,'w')
```

I expect that the os.path.basename will open up the folder and create it in that location like in html you can use /../ but syntax is different.
What I currently have is no results and if it does work, I'm unfamiliar where this is being created. Please help

Comment: Update: Found out it saves to where the Sikuli Executable is located but still have not found out how to specify a folder in a different location.